# Global onclick handler vs. per-element event handlers

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Consider this example:
You're creating a website that uses client-side rendering.
When the user clicks a link, you want to disable the browser's navigation and render the new page yourself.

Perhaps you also have some html like this, and you want to call `upvote_post(id)` every time the button is clicked:

```html
<post-element data-id=12345> 
   ... 
   <upvote-button></upvote-button>
</post-element>
```

The common way to handle both of these cases would be to add a `click` event handler on every `<a>`, `<upvote-button>`, etc. element that you generate.

But wouldn't it be better to just add an event handler on the document itself?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    for (let elem of e.path) {
        if (elem instanceof HTMLAnchorElement && elem.origin==window.location.origin) {
            e.preventDefault()
            render_page(elem.href)
            break
        } else if (elem.tagName=='UPVOTE-BUTTON') {
            let post = elem.closest('post-element')
            upvote_post(post.dataset.id)
            break
        }
    }
})
```

Of course, it feels wrong to bypass the builtin event handler system, but I can't think of any disadvantages here.
You can still add event handlers to specific elements if you need to, but for common actions, this seems like a better solution.

Comment: Its called event delegation and one con is that it kind of breaks encapsulation. It *can* work, but now you have to make sure nothing in the bubbling stops the event from getting to document and document has to handle ***all*** of the events (thats a lot of responsibility). Dont optimize prematurely.

Comment: oh yeah, I can see how that might be a problem in some cases (not for what I'm doing though)
As far as optimization goes, yeah I'm not too concerned about some tiny performance improvements here, this is mostly just an effort to simplify my code.